# Excel: how to highlight the max value of each row only if the maximum value is a certain value larger than the min value?

Tags: excel, formatting, conditional-statements

I want to highlight the maximum value of a cell if that maximum value is larger than the minimum value by 5.

68.3 64.3 62.6 65.5 66.3 75.9

So in this case, 75.9 (max val) - 62.6 (min value) >=5 so the max value should be highlighted.

I tried using conditional formatting with this

```
=max(if (max(A1:F1)-min(A1-F1)>=5, 1,0))
```

and

```
=max(A1:F1)-min(A1:F1)>=5
```

which highlighted all the cells..

So, any thoughts on how to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In this case which value will be highlighted?

Comment: Do you need to highlight all values that are >= 5 larger than minimum?

Comment: @JvdV Just the maximum value should be highlighted if max val-min val>=5

Comment: You have a nice answer down by Tom that seems to do the trick @GraceHJKim

Answer (score 1):

To highlight just the maximum value, given that it is at least 5 greater than the minimum, try

```
=AND(A2=MAX($A2:$F2),A2>=MIN($A2:$F2)+5)
```

where the range starts at A2.

[image]

Note that this uses absolute addressing for the range of columns used to calculate Max and Min (**$A**2:**$F**2), but relative addressing for the rows ($A**2**:$F**2**). If the formula is applied to row 3 (say), this will automatically change to

```
=AND(A3=MAX($A3:$F3),A3>=MIN($A3:$F3)+5)
```

---

Here is an example where the formula is applied to two rows - the formula is exactly the same, only the 'Applies to' section is changed:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Tom. Is it possible so that this formula is applied in all rows? I tried for the second row, but even when I changed the row number, it would not apply on the third row.

Comment: When you have a formula that works for the second row, if you use relative addressing for the rows (i.e. put A2 and not A$2) it will automatically work for other rows. You just need to change the range that it applies to - will paste a screenshot into my answer.